# Subtracting unclosed path in Sketch

Tags: sketch-app

I essentially want to subtract a dotted, unclosed path from a background shape in Sketch. I can see why this doesn't work, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do what I want to do (subtract the dotted shapes from the background shape). I think I'd have to expand the stroke (or in Sketch's case, border), but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Here it is before subtraction:
[image: Map Image]

Here it is afterward (it is essentially closing the path before subtracting it)
[image: After Subtraction]

Answer (score 1):

I realized I could vectorize the stroke just as I finished writing the question. This solves the problem perfectly.